# why is cURL not reading full @file and setting Content-Length: 8186?

Tags: curl, content-length

I am using cURL on Windows 7 to test a RESTful API.

My data is in a JSON file that is 16,987 characters long.

When I do not set the content length cURL assumes `Content-Length: 8186` and does not send the entire JSON payload. I get `Unexpected end-of-input` from the server.

When I do set `-H "Content-Length: 17000"` cURL seems to send off the first 8186 bytes without properly structuring the request body (or something)... the server takes some time thinking about this and finally gives `400 Bad Request`.

with no explicit content type header:

```
C:\...>curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Expect:" -H "Authorization=Bearer ...etc..." --data @quotedGood.json https://web.domain.com/NewApp/rest/invoice/
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x60006a600; line 1103 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 192.168.0.0...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x60006a600; line 1156 (connection #0)
* Connected to web.domain.com (192.168.0.0) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x60006a600; line 1253 (connection #0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x60006a600; line 1267 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=CA; ST=prov; L=town; O=Company; CN=*.domain.com
*        start date: Mar  5 17:57:58 2015 GMT
*        expire date: Nov 10 23:57:20 2018 GMT
*        subjectAltName: web.domain.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=...etc...
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x60006a600; line 1288 (connection #0)
> POST /NewApp/rest/invoice/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: web.domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 8186
>
* upload completely sent off: 8186 out of 8186 bytes
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x60006a600; line 1350 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x60006a600; line 1477 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x60006a600; line 1487 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2018 21:37:26 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Set-Cookie: SERVERID=web8; path=/; HttpOnly; Secure
< Connection: close
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
<
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x60006a600; line 1645 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
* Expire cleared
{"summary":"There was a problem with your invoice request. If you require technical assistance, please note the following identifier [NEWAPP-EX-646744087] to help trace the issue.","timestamp":"2018-03-05 16:37:26.105","errorMsgs":["Unexpected end-of-input in field name\n at [Source: org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.MessageBodyReaderContextImpl$InputStreamWrapper@74d44e80; line: 245, column: 205]"]}
```

With an explicit content length. Note the same log as above `* upload completely sent off: 8186 out of 8186 bytes`, even though the Content-Length is 17000... make me think cURL is not reading the whole file:

```
C:\...>curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Content-Length: 17000" -H "Expect:" -H "Authorization=Bearer ...etc..." --data @quotedGood.json https://web.domain.com/NewApp/rest/invoice/
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
* STATE: INIT => CONNECT handle 0x60006a690; line 1103 (connection #-5000)
* Added connection 0. The cache now contains 1 members
*   Trying 192.168.0.0...
* STATE: CONNECT => WAITCONNECT handle 0x60006a690; line 1156 (connection #0)
* Connected to web.domain.com (192.168.0.0) port 443 (#0)
* STATE: WAITCONNECT => SENDPROTOCONNECT handle 0x60006a690; line 1253 (connection #0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* STATE: SENDPROTOCONNECT => PROTOCONNECT handle 0x60006a690; line 1267 (connection #0)
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=CA; ST=prov; L=town; O=Company; CN=*.domain.com
*        start date: Mar  5 17:57:58 2015 GMT
*        expire date: Nov 10 23:57:20 2018 GMT
*        subjectAltName: web.domain.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=Entrust, Inc.; OU=...etc...
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
* STATE: PROTOCONNECT => DO handle 0x60006a690; line 1288 (connection #0)
> POST /NewApp/rest/invoice/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: web.domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 17000
>
* upload completely sent off: 8186 out of 8186 bytes
* STATE: DO => DO_DONE handle 0x60006a690; line 1350 (connection #0)
* STATE: DO_DONE => WAITPERFORM handle 0x60006a690; line 1477 (connection #0)
* STATE: WAITPERFORM => PERFORM handle 0x60006a690; line 1487 (connection #0)
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2018 21:48:11 GMT
< Content-Length: 226
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
< X-Frame-Options: DENY
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
<
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
</body></html>
* STATE: PERFORM => DONE handle 0x60006a690; line 1645 (connection #0)
* Curl_done
* Closing connection 0
* The cache now contains 0 members
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what I had in the end when I finally got it working, in a cmd prompt on Windows 7

`curl --request POST ^
     --url http://127.0.0.1:8080/MyApp/rest/invoice ^
     --header "Content-Type:application/json" ^
     --header "Authorization:  some-proprietary-auth-code" ^
     --header "Content-Length:9905" --header "Expect:" ^
     --data-binary "@.\compressedGood.json"`

`compressedGood.json` is a file with un-escaped, double-quoted fields and all spaces and `eol`s removed. Like:

```
{"externalId":null,"companyName":ACME,"companyProvince":ON,"salesFirstName":null,"salesLastName":null,"products":[ {"name":"Name of Product", ... etc  ... } ] }
```

Comment: The `--data-binary` solved it for me. My file is much better (~100Kb) and only part of it would be send (~44Kb). I'm thinking that since I have a binary file, they may have stopped on the first `\0`. In any event, marking the file as binary was the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Content-Length` header is ignored by the `Transfer-Encoding` header.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) you could try with `-H "Transfer-Encoding: identity"`

Comment: I did not settle on this as a solution but it put me on the right track, thanks.